# Chrome devtools: long GPU task. How to investigate?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, devtools, phaserjs

I'm experimenting with Phaser.js and wrote a simple game. It runs smoothly, but from time to time I  see a sudden frame drop. Nothing happens to cause this. No explosions, additional calculations, or anything like that. It's running as usual, then freezing, and then everything's back to normal.

The Performance tab shows this:

[dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbST6.png)

The main JS thread is idling, and generally nothing's going on, except for the long GPU task that comes out of nowhere. Unfortunately, there's no detailed information available for it. Is there a way to investigate what's going on there?

So far I've tried to play with different Phaser.js settings, such as render options and resolution, but that changed nothing at all. It's difficult to do anything without knowing what causes the issue.

Comment: did you try your game in a different browser, just to see if it is a phaser specific problem, or simply a browser _(chrome)_ issue? Or/And have you tried it on a different Device PC or Phone, just to rule out the device a source of the issue.

Comment: @winner_joiner great idea. I've tried the game in another browser, and it runs smoothly. Then I completely restarted Chrome, and can't reproduce the issue after that. I'll have to keep an eye on it, but maybe this was really purely Chrome-related. It'd still be nice to know how to debug GPU issues like that in devtools (if possible).